# Caching JSON on server using expiration date?

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents, file-put-contents, cache-expiration

This is some working code that I wrote to call a JSON file and cache it on my servers.

I'm calling the cached file. If the file exists I use json_decode on it. If the file doesn't exist I then call the JSON and decode that. Then after calling the JSON url, I write the contents to the cached file url.

```
$cache = @file_get_contents('cache/'.$filename.'.txt');

 //check to see if file exists:
if (strlen($cache)<1) {

    // file is empty
    echo '<notcached />';
    $JSON1= @file_get_contents($url);

    $JSON_Data1 = json_decode($JSON1);

    $myfile = fopen('cache/'.$filename.'.txt', "w");
    $put = file_put_contents('cache/'.$filename.'.txt', ($JSON1));

} else {

    //if file doesn't exist:
    $JSON_Data1 = json_decode($cache);
    echo '<cached />';
}
```

Instead of only using  `if (strlen($cache)<1) {`, is there a way that I can check the age of the $filename.txt and if it's older than 30 days grab the JSON url in the else statement?

Comment: You could use `filemtime()` to check the last modified time (http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php).

Comment: filetime does seem like the correct command. Do you know how I might write an if statement that if filetime > 30 days old { ?

Comment: `if (filemtime('cache/'.$filename.'.txt') > strtotime('now -30 day')) {}` Would do it. Also checking on `file_exists('cache/'.$filename.'.txt')` is better than trying to load it in with error suppression.

Comment: Why do you `fopen()`?

Comment: thanks @IncredibleHat ! NigelRen's spinoff of your recommendation works. Unfortunately, I think I'm going to delete this question though since everyone seems to think it was worth downvoting. Wish I knew why my questions often get downvotes. I think this question and all of your answers will be really helpful to people coming in from Google search, but ok...

Comment: ... it seemed a fine enough question. I don't know. The original code was rough, and obviously not a right way to do it... but thats why you were asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like

```
$file = 'cache/'.$filename.'.txt';
$modify = filemtime($file);
//check to see if file exists:
if ($modify == false || $modify < strtotime('now -30 day')) {
    // file is empty, or too old
    echo '<notcached />';
} else {
    // Good to use file
    echo '<cached />';
}
```

`filemtime()` returns the last modified time of the file, the if statement checks that the file exists (`filemtime` returns false if it fails) or the file was last modified more than 30 days ago.

OR...
to check if the file exists or too old (without warnings)

```
$file = 'cache/'.$filename.'.txt';
if (file_exists($file) == false || filemtime($file) < strtotime('now -30 day')) {
    // file is empty, or too old
    echo '<notcached />';
} else {
    // Good to use file
    echo '<cached />';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nigel! I tested this with if (file_exists($file) == false || filemtime($file) < strtotime('now -1 minute')) {  and it looks like it works! Unfortunately, I'll probably delete this question since everyone seems to think it was worth downvoting for some reason. Wish I knew why my stuff gets downvoted

Comment: I gave up worrying about down-voting, I used to ask why and didn't usually get anything helpful.  Most important thing is you've solved this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've used a simple file cache class in my previous projects, I think that should help you. I think it's easy to understand, the cache time is in seconds and the `setFilename` function cleans the filename in case it contains invalid characters.

```
<?php

class SimpleFileCache
{
    var $cache_path = 'cache/';
    var $cache_time = 3600;
    var $cache_file;

    function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->setFilename($name);
    }

    function getFilename()
    {
        return $this->cache_file;
    }

    function setFilename($name)
    {
        $this->cache_file = $this->cache_path . preg_replace('/[^0-9a-z\.\_\-]/', '', strtolower($name));
    }

    function isCached()
    {
        return (file_exists($this->cache_file) && (filemtime($this->cache_file) + $this->cache_time >= time()));
    }

    function getData()
    {
        return file_get_contents($this->cache_file);
    }

    function setData($data)
    {
        if (!empty($data)) {
            return file_put_contents($this->cache_file, $data) > 0;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

It can be used like this.

```
<?php

require_once 'SimpleFileCache.php';

$cache = new SimpleFileCache('cache.json');
if ($cache->isCached()) {
    $json = $cache->getData();
} else {
    $json = json_encode($someData); // set your cache data
    $cache->setData($json);
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $json;
```